# Intuitive idea to consider strict epimorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, epimorphisms

In a category with fiber products, a morphism $Y\to X$ is said to be strict epimorphism if the sequence is exact: $Y\times_XY\xrightarrow{p_1,p_2}Y\to X$, (here the first arrow should be a double arrow which means two parallel maps).

What is the motivation to define the concept of strict epimorphism?

(I read about it in Milne's Etale Cohomology 2.17, where he showed a faithfully flat morphism of finite type is a strict epimorphism)

Comment: A more common term is effective epimorphism: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism. For some discussion see https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/regular-and-effective-monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/.

Comment: There is a more general definition of [strict epimorphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+epimorphism). Ultimately, the goal is to find the right generalisation of "surjection" to general categories.

Comment: Did you try to show this is an epimorphism yourself? It's immediate from the definition of a coequalizer.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes you are right.